# Getting INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE error

Tags: appium-android

Appium Server version: 1.7.1

OS: Windows 8

While running the code I got

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. 
Original error:
  Error executing adbExec.
Original error:
  'Command 'D\:\\Android\\android-sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 8080 -s ------ install  C\:\\Users\\resi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\appium-desktop\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-unlock \\bin\\unlock_apk-debug.apk' exited with code 1';
Stderr: 'Failed to install C:\Users\resi\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop \resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-unlock\bin\unlock_apk-debug.apk:
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE:
  Package io.appium.unlock signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]'; Code: '1'
```

error and Appium Setting page is opened and instant closed in real Android device instead of opening app (.apk file)

Comment: Your apk is signed by different certificate. Simple solution: uninstall previous version from device. Good solution: sign new apk using previous certificate, but it might be impossible if it was a development autogenerated certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cleanup the device you are using:

1. Go to Settings -> Apps
2. Delete you application under test using `Uninstall for all users` menu
3. Delete Appium Settings app

Restart your test and it should work

Comment: Thanks! already followed above steps multiple times but facing same error still. And while running code Appium Settings app install automatically and getting opened on real device and throw same error in the console.

Comment: Hm, so far I've been testing lots of real devices and multiple brands and haven't seen where it was not working. What is the device name and OS version?

Comment: device name is Nexus 6 and OS version is windows 8

Comment: device name is Nexus 6 and OS version is windows 8. In my case it was not launching the app, it was only launch the appium setting only for 2 sec and close it.

Comment: package tests;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
public class TestTest{
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
File app=new File("app.apk");

Comment: DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 6");
caps.setCapability("udid", "------"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsoluteFile());
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.app.app");
caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.app.app.Activity");
caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> drive = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),caps);
}}

Comment: Above two comments are using in coding.

Comment: You are mixing issues. Now you don't have all capabilities: where are `appWaitActivity` and `appWaitPackage` capabilities? `Udid` is not required for Android, check the proper capabilities and you will fix the issue.

Comment: Can you please explain more and any reference link.

Comment: Check about capabilities: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md

Comment: platformName: 'Android’,
    automationName: 'UiAutomator2', //remove in case you are running on Android less than 5
    deviceName: 'Android Emulator',
    appWaitActivity: <activity appium should wait to be started>,
    appWaitPackage: <package of activity above>,
app: <path to app>

Comment: i tried above changed, but getting same error. please help
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'path\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 5bc2478f install C\:path\\unlock_apk-debug.apk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'Failed to install C:path\bin\unlock_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package io.appium.unlock signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]'; Code: '1'